# Trouble with DayNight mode status bar/controls inconsistently themed after recreate

Tags: android, android-theme

I'm having quite a bit of trouble getting the DayNight theme to play nicely after a preference change and activity.recreate() call. Depending on the value (and which SDK I'm on), I get inconsistent theming (icons are dark on dark or light on light).

In my PreferenceFragment, I have a preference that allows the user to set one of three values: Light, Dark, or Auto, which correspond with AppCompatDelegates MODE_NIGHT_NO, MODE_NIGHT_YES, or MODE_NIGHT_AUTO, respectively. Here's what the implementation looks like:

PreferenceFragment.kt

```
override fun onPreferenceChange(preference: Preference, value: Any): Boolean {
    setSummary(preference, value.toString())

    return when (preference.key) {
        themePreference.key -> consume {
            AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(appSharedPreferences.string(R.string.preference_theme_key).toInt())
            activity?.recreate()
        }
    }
}
```

BaseActivity.kt

```
 override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(appSharedPreferences.string(R.string.preference_theme_key).toInt())

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
}
```

I've also tried combinations of:

`delegate.setLocalNightMode(appSharedPreferences.string(R.string.preference_theme_key).toInt())`

and

`AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(appSharedPreferences.string(R.string.preference_theme_key).toInt()`

peppered into different places in the activity/application lifecycle with no success.

What I'm seeing mostly is dark icons on a dark status bar, and inconsistencies on pre-P app switcher (the theme is Night, but the app switcher toolbar shows up as a light theme). I don't appear to have issues with the theme of my own app controls, like tabs or text - it's mainly on the android system views like the status bar and app switcher toolbar).

If I kill the app and re-launch, I have no issues whatsoever. It's only after an activity.recreate call do I see these issues.

Comment: Same problem here... Status bar changes color to black but icons stay black too... They are not turning white after recreate... Did you managed to solved it somehow?

Comment: Nope. I'm hoping an update in the material library will eventually fix this. It's frustratingly buggy though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After searching for a simple solution for a long while, I found an attribute that conveniently handles this scenario. I'm not sure how proper this approach is, but from my testing it works as expected.

Given that you're using `Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight` or some similar variant in your style XML, you can use `?attr/isLightTheme` as a true/false flag.

```
<item name="android:windowLightStatusBar">?attr/isLightTheme</item>
```

The value returned by `?attr/isLightTheme` is handled by the system. You can check the current value with:

```
AppCompatDelegate.getDefaultNightMode();

// or

Configuration configuration = getResources().getConfiguration();
int currentNightMode = configuration.uiMode & Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_MASK;
```

Comment: I believe Google decided to beef up bugfixing efforts when dark mode was announced as a big OS feature. My issue was fixed, but this isn't a bad solution, so I'll mark as accepted. Thanks!